# Show image without link if image has no link

Tags: php

I would like to show a different image if the image does not have a link

JS Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/xm3ecb59/1/

```
<?php if (!empty('url')){ ?>
<a href="">
    <img src="dog.jpg" width="400" alt="">
</a>

<?php } else { ?>

<img ="/cat.jpg" width="500" alt="">

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: because you have no src

Comment: add image src path to view image

Comment: Yes, i know it needs a image src. I would like to show the cat.jpg because there is no web address in the <a href="">

Comment: Which url do you check? Now you check if the string 'url' is empty, which is ever false because it's a string with 'url' in it.

Answer (score 1):

You just add `src` like...

```
<?php if (!empty('url')){ ?>
   <a href="http//:www.go.com">
         <img src="" width="400" alt="">
   </a>

<?php } else { ?>

         <img src="path to image/cat.jpg" width="500" alt="">

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Yes, i know it needs a image src. I would like to show the cat.jpg because there is no web address in the <a href="">